# Which Hibernate FetchMode will cause collections to be lazy-loaded?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, lazy-loading

I asked a this question on the Hibernate forums, but did not get a full response, so I thought I'd repost it here. Here's the original question thread:

http://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1008243&p=2438963#p2438963

In a nutshell, I have a custom HQL query that joins together two completely unrelated tables, and I'm trying to prevent the "O(N+1) selects" problem by disabling the loading of associated collections that exist in my Hibernate-mapped POJOs.

Apparently, I can use Hibernate [fetch profiles](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-profiles) for this, but there's a snag. Here's what Hibernate's FetchMode.java says:

```
/**
 * Fetch using an outer join. Equivalent to <tt>fetch="join"</tt>.
 */
public static final FetchMode JOIN = new FetchMode("JOIN");
/**
 * Fetch eagerly, using a separate select. Equivalent to
 * <tt>fetch="select"</tt>.
 */
public static final FetchMode SELECT = new FetchMode("SELECT");

/**
 * Fetch lazily. Equivalent to <tt>outer-join="false"</tt>.
  * @deprecated use <tt>FetchMode.SELECT</tt>
 */
public static final FetchMode LAZY = SELECT;
```

So, "LAZY" isn't really lazy, it's just "SELECT", which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Is there a fetch mode that will prevent collections from being loaded ? If not, is there some other way to disable the loading of collections during the course of a specific HQL query ?

I realize that the conventional way to accomplish this is to use Criteria queries, but I need to do a join on an arbitrary property, and as far as I can tell, there are no Criteria for that.

Answer (score 5):

First, I believe the default behaviour of hibernate is to use lazy-loading. So check if it is not already the case.

Then, I believe they have mistaken the comments in the documentation, and `SELECT` should really be a lazy fetch (if you check the documentation of the newest version of hibernate, the 'eagerly' word is removed).