# SetFetchMode Lazy doesn't overwrite ClassMap settings

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, lazy-loading

In `Criteria` I do `SetFetchMode` as `Lazy` but still fetching all items, how can I fix this?

```
public class MenuItem : BaseClass<MenuItem>
{
    public virtual int MenuItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<MenuItem> Children { get; set; }
    public virtual MenuItem Parent { get; set; }

    public MenuItem()
    {
         Children = new List<MenuItem>();
    }
}

class MenuItemMap : ClassMap<MenuItem>
{
    public MenuItemMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.MenuItemId);
        Map(x => x.Text);
        HasMany(x => x.Children).KeyColumn("ParentId").Not.LazyLoad().Fetch.Select();
        References(x => x.Parent).Not.LazyLoad().Fetch.Select(); 
    }
}

using (var session = NHibernateHelper<T>.OpenSession())
{
    var CC = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T));

    CC.SetFetchMode("Children", FetchMode.Lazy);

    return CC.List<T>();
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the class definition of `MenuItem`? Especially how you defined the `Children` collection

Comment: I added class definition

Comment: I had hoped you had forgotten to use `virtual` everywhere, or had used `List<MenuItem> Children` :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to say, that this is not possible. Our *JAVA* brother `Hibernate` *(from which NHibernate was ported into .NET)* seems to have that option:

- [Hibernate: Enabling lazy fetching in Criteria API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2222840/1679310)

But NHibernate does not support that. Chek also [Override lazy loading behavior 'lazy=false'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30166946/1679310).

What we can do, is to bet on `Projections`. This way we really assemble exactly one SQL statement and get a list of Transformed objects (semi-filled, dependent on amount of selected properties)

#### [16.6. Projections](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover-projections)

[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26071378/1679310) an example how to build a deep projections *(including References/many-to-one)*
[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24248309/1679310) how to transform them into originally mapped object Graph.